# Two Hosts - Redirect to different host by IP?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, iis, dns

We are developing a new website for a client on Wordpress (Apache).  Their current website is an ASP solution hosted on an IIS server.

Our client does not have access to the IIS host (he is not paying for it, and he doesn't even know the account it's being hosted on).  He wishes to keep the old website for reference.

We have the domain registrar information and can update the DNS/IP information accordingly.

We have ordered a new Apache server for the new Wordpress site.  Is it possible to do the following via .htaccess on the new host (assuming we change the DNS to point to the new host)?

- direct all traffic to the new host with the wordpress website
- redirect only a specific IP to the old host containing the ASP website

Is this even possible?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Is this even possible?` Yes and No. You can't redirect to 2 different servers with the same hostname. If you were on the same server you might be able to do some documentroot trickery with conditions but you're not. So you'd have to redirect the specific IP to something like old.example.com with an entry in DNS for the old subdomain pointing to the old asp site.

Comment: Thanks Panama Jack, I would be fine with the following config: old.domainname.com for the old site and domainname.com for the new site.  Is there a way to do this since I don't have access to the old host to make the change to point it to the subdomain?